# External JS file button call

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to make a wage calculator for a resume page. My function works when its internal however, when I change it to external my button and function do not work.Im' trying to do this in the center div. Ignored the other pages section as these are just links.
Any help is greatly appreciated!

Here is my HTML:

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>

 <!--External-->

 <head>


<title>Resume of Michael R. Young </title>
<link rel = "stylesheet" href = "michaelyoung.css"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="work.js"></script>
</head>


<body>

<div>
 <h1><img src="Banner.jpeg" alt="Banner" style="width:750px;height:100px;"> </h1> 

 <div class = 'main'> <!-- Main gray div -->
 <h4> Wage Calculator</h4>
  <!--border-->
 <div class = 'left' > <!-- Left div -->
  <p> Other pages </p>
  <p><a href="School.html"  title="Schools I have attended."> School</a></p>
  <p><a href="Contact.html" title="Contact information">Contact</a></p>
  <p><a href="Awards.html" title="Awards I've receieved.">Awards</a></p>
  <p><a href="Degrees.html" title="Years and Degrees earned.">Degrees</a></p>

</div>


 <div class = 'center'> <!-- Center div Took out inline but not working-->
 <h3> Salary calculator</h3>



<p> Enter wage per hours: <input type="text" id="textOne" /></p>
<p> Enter hours per week: <input type="text" id="textTwo" /></p>


<input type="button" onclick="getText()" value="Check" />
<p id="change"></p>


</div>



  </div>
  </div>

</body>
</html>`
```

My javascript:

```
     <script>

function getText(){

  //access the element with the id 'textOne' and get its value
  //assign this value to the variable theText
  var theText = document.getElementById('textOne').value;

  //alert("Your Hourly Wage is: " + theText);

var hours= document.getElementById('textTwo').value;
//alert("Your hours per week is: " + hours);



var hourlywage=document.getElementById('textOne').value;//saving in hourlywage

var hoursWorked=document.getElementById('textTwo').value;//saving in hoursWorked


var wage = parseInt(hourlywage);//changing to INT
//document.write(wage);
var hours = parseInt(hoursWorked);//changing to INT
//document.write(hours);

var totalpay= (wage * hours)*52;

if(totalpay<20000)
{
    document.getElementById("change").innerHTML ="Yearly salary of: $"+totalpay +" is too low thank you!";

}
else if(totalpay>20000 && totalpay<25000)
{
document.getElementById("change").innerHTML ="Yearly salary of: $"+totalpay +" is close lets negotiate!";
}
else
{
document.getElementById("change").innerHTML ="Yearly salary of: $"+totalpay + " is just right!"
}


//document.write(totalpay);


}

</script>
```

Comment: Can you see whether `work.js` is being loaded when it is an external file?  If you use [Chrome Developer Tools](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/setup/workspace/setup-devtools) you can check whether the file is served successfully.

Answer (score 0):

you need to move js to the bottom of the page:

```
 ....
 </div>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="work.js"></script>

</body>
</html>`
```